# web scraping - The site is showing different content to my scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I develop a project for my college that take data from my team and do some statistics operations and other stuff. The website from I get the data is this: http://www.acb.com/club/estadisticas/id/13

I want to get data for different seasons, but when I run my code the content I get is different to the website, for example, for 2014 stats:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrap_web(page):
    pageTree = requests.get(page)
    pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')
    TeamPage = pageSoup.find('div',{"class":'estadisticas_plantilla'}).find('tr',{"class": 'totales'})
    ValuesList = TeamPage.text.split('\n')[2:-1]

    arr = list(ValuesList)
    return arr


urltest = "http://www.acb.com/club/estadisticas/id/13/temporada_id/2014"

print(scrap_web(urltest))
```

The data I receive is from this season not from 2014 season. The problem maybe that the content was injected into the page via javascript?

Comment: Yes, it updates using JavaScript.

Comment: Ignore that comment. I saw a difference because I let Chrome translate the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some years assigned PHPSESSID not changes and return wrong data even in browser. Get `http://www.acb.com/club/estadisticas/id/13` before actually years worked for me.

After some tries:

```
import random

user_agents = [
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; FSL 7.0.6.01001)",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; FSL 7.0.7.01001)",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; FSL 7.0.5.01003)",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; de; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100723 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.8",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; de; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100723 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.8",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)",
    "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.01",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.02",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0) Opera 7.02 Bork-edition [en]",
]
cookies = {
    'acepta_uso_cookies': '1',
}
headers = {
    'acepta_uso_cookies': "1",
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'DNT': '1',
    'User-Agent': random.sample(user_agents, 1)[0],
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    s.get('http://www.acb.com/club/estadisticas/id/13', cookies=cookies)

    for year in range(2019, 2012, -1):
        response = s.get(f'http://www.acb.com/club/estadisticas/id/13/temporada_id/{year}', cookies=cookies)
        s.headers['Referer'] = f'http://www.acb.com/club/estadisticas/id/13/temporada_id/{year + 1}'
        pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        TeamPage = pageSoup.find('div', {"class": 'estadisticas_plantilla'}).find('tr', {"class": 'totales'})
        ValuesList = TeamPage.text.split('\n')[2:-1]
        print(year, list(ValuesList))
```

> 2019 ['Totales', '18', '\xa0', '\xa0', '85,6', '9,8', '26,3', '37,1%',
>   '21,0', '37,9', '55,4%', '14,2', '17,6', '80,7%', '25,6', '11,6',
>   '37,2', '16,3', '6,8', '12,0', '1,9', '2,4', '3,2', '17,7', '20,4',
>   '\xa0', '99,3']
>  2018 ['Totales', '40', '\xa0', '\xa0', '81,1',
>   '10,2', '27,0', '37,8%', '19,0', '33,6', '56,5%', '12,5', '15,5',
>   '80,7%', '23,4', '10,2', '33,6', '17,6', '5,4', '12,0', '1,6', '2,3',
>   '3,2', '18,0', '19,4', '\xa0', '92,1']
>  2017 ['Totales', '37',
>   '\xa0', '\xa0', '82,1', '10,8', '26,0', '41,4%', '17,5', '33,5',
>   '52,1%', '14,9', '18,9', '78,8%', '24,2', '9,5', '33,7', '16,7',
>   '6,1', '11,5', '1,6', '2,3', '2,3', '18,4', '20,8', '\xa0',
>   '93,5']
>  2016 ['Totales', '43', '\xa0', '\xa0', '81,8', '8,7',
>   '23,3', '37,3%', '20,1', '36,7', '54,7%', '15,5', '20,0', '77,7%',
>   '24,4', '9,7', '34,1', '17,6', '7,0', '12,7', '1,7', '2,2', '1,8',
>   '19,0', '21,9', '\xa0', '94,4']
>  2015 ['Totales', '40', '\xa0',
>   '\xa0', '82,8', '9,0', '23,2', '38,9%', '20,3', '37,1', '54,7%',
>   '15,1', '18,8', '80,4%', '24,5', '9,6', '34,0', '17,5', '7,2', '11,9',
>   '2,5', '2,8', '1,9', '20,1', '22,1', '\xa0', '96,6']
>  2014
>   ['Totales', '41', '\xa0', '\xa0', '83,0', '9,2', '23,9', '38,4%',
>   '20,1', '36,7', '54,8%', '15,3', '19,3', '79,1%', '22,0', '9,9',
>   '31,9', '16,7', '7,8', '12,7', '2,2', '1,8', '1,5', '23,3', '22,4',
>   '\xa0', '90,7']
>  2013 ['Totales', '42', '\xa0', '\xa0', '84,0',
>   '9,5', '24,3', '38,9%', '20,0', '38,0', '52,6%', '15,6', '18,9',
>   '82,8%', '23,9', '9,3', '33,3', '17,8', '9,0', '11,6', '2,3', '2,3',
>   '1,9', '20,7', '21,3', '\xa0', '96,9']

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat different from your code, but it can get you close enough to what you need, and you can take it from there:

```
url = "http://www.acb.com/club/estadisticas/id/13/temporada_id/2014"
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

resp = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(resp.text,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
lower = table.select_one('tr.cabecera_general').findNextSibling()
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
columns = []
rows = []

for c in lower.find_all('th'):
    columns.append(c.text)
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    rows.append(row)

games = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
games
```

Comment: Your code is great and I take some ideas about this, but I still get different data. In this case I want to obtain the data from 2014 season but I get the 2020 season.